# Does a router perform an error detection and correction?

Tags: router

Does the router perform an error checking for the data that passes through it, or something that affects the data apart from routing them to the destination?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Ron wrote, routers just check and drop errors, there's no correction.

Usually, you leave forward error correction (FEC) to the physical layer where the trade-off between cost, performance and reliability is best decided.

For Ethernet, 10 GbE introduced optional FEC which has become mandatory for many faster PHYs (because with growing speed it gets harder and harder to reliably transmit error-free data without FEC).

The Ethernet FCS is a simple checksum on layer 2 which just drops error frames, just like higher layer checksums.

Answer (score 2):

Routers may perform some error detection, but they will not perform error corrections.

If the layer-1/2 protocol is something like ethernet, which has the FCS field, the hardware should drop any frames with a bad FCS.

IPv4 has the Header Checksum field, and it must match the IPv4 header, otherwise the packet is dropped.

IPv6 has eliminated the IPv4 Header Checksum in favor of letting the lower and upper protocols determine errors and perform any error detection.

Comment: This is generally true, but there are a couple of exceptions for certain line protocols/serial line disciplines that *did* have error correction as well as detection (think low-speed satellite/radio links).  I haven't personally seen any of them in action in quite a while, though.

Comment: @rnxrx, that is true, but I was trying not to confuse the situation because that isn't really a routing function. I debated even mentioning ethernet, but I did because that is usually the next question, and it is so common.

Comment: No question, @Ron Maupin - just remembering weird trivia.  It wouldn't be the Internet without it!